# Join by row info in a table instead of a column

Tags: mysql

All,
I have two tables that I'm trying to get information out of in a single query. The first table is `wp_bmt_galleries` and it has a `gallery_id` as the primary key. I also have another column as the `team_id`. I then have another table which is how I want to join these tables together. This table is called `wp_bmt_postmeta` and has a `meta_key` and a `meta_value` column. These two columns have data like this:

```
meta_key       meta_value
bmt_team_id    1
bmt_gallery_id 2
```

I want to join these two tables by the `team_id` but the only way I know how to do a join is by column but in this example it needs to be by row.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the third table? wp_bmt_team?  Do you want to join the gallery and team by what is in the meta data?

Comment: can you explain it a little better? what's the structure of wp_bmt_galleries? and you say there's three tables but you only name 2 (wp_bmt_galleries and wp_bmt_postmeta). What's the structure of that second table, what do you want as the result of the join? can you put an example input and output?

Comment: @ChrisBarlow The third table is wp_bmt_posts. I can join the wp_bmt_post_meta with the wp_bmt_posts table by post_id so I'm not worried about that table.

Comment: You want to get the row in `wp_bmt_galleries` whose `gallery_id` is `2`, because that's the value of `bmt_gallery_id` in the second table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the `meta_value` column to the `gallery_id` column, and then use a `WHERE` clause to select the appropriate row from the metainfo table.

```
SELECT g.*
FROM wp_bmt_galleries AS g
JOIN wp_bmt_postmeta AS m ON g.gallery_id = m.meta_value
WHERE m.meta_key = 'bmt_gallery_id`
```